# STM32F103 USB CDC - device descriptor request failed

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device, port

I'm working on a custom device which has to communicate with a PC over a virtual com port. I'm using STM32CubeIDE with code generated by the included STM32CubeMX. Here's a little information about my setup:

I have a STM32F103RET6 MCU conencted to a MicroUSB port via USBLC6-2SC6 protection device. I'm using code generated by the CubeMX software.
Here are a couple of screenshots:
[image: USB settings tab]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm aware that on the PCB the resistor which is supposed to pull D+ line to 3v3 is floating - I've fixed that with a thin wire, and tried hooking it up directly to 3V3 and to a GPIO pin, to set and reset it dynamically, but neither has helped me. The code is 100% purely generated from CubeMX, with a small addition of writing PA3 pin high to pull D+ up through the resistor. That's it. Whenever the MCU drives PA3 high, win10 PC says that the device could not be recognized. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the crystal runs at 16 MHz, or rather, are you sure that the code does not drop to HSI due to CSS because of HSE problem? The MCU runs at correct speed? There is no regulator schematics or more PCB to see crystal and regulator. Not a single bypass cap in sight either.

Comment: @Justme I'll check the oscillator with an oscilloscope tomorrow. I ommited the power supply part of the schematic, but the regulator is TLV1117LV33DCYR, and there are multiple decoupling capacitors, both at the regulator input, regulator output, and close to STM32 supply pins (100pF, 100nF, 1uF values)

Comment: You could check the oscillator, but it would be more beneficial to check which oscillator is actually in use and what frequency the core is running, because just poking the crystal with probe might give it a transient which will trigger CSS or PLL unlock.

Comment: How would I go about checking that? Is there a CSS register I can read to see if HSE is in use?

Comment: @Justme or how would I check actual clock value, except for measuring ticks over a period of time?

Comment: You can output sysclock on MCO. You can blink a LED at 1 Hz assuming what the sysclock is. If the LED blinks at different speed, the sysclock is different too.

Comment: You can also configure a UART (since you have the pins traced to your expansion connectors), transmit data from the MCU, and check the baud rate using a scope or logic analyzer.  Having a debug log UART during MCU development is always a good idea.

Comment: Makes sense. Just to make sure - does the CubeMX usb work out of the box? Or am I missing some implementations that user needs to himself?

Comment: Do you have any update on the issue? I'm facing the exact same situation with my board.